# paintComponent telling me im using an object not a graphic

Tags: java, paint, draw, paintcomponent, graphic

Basically i have this code

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("http://i.imgur.com/UKmK7j0.jpg")); //Image is just an example

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    image.paintIcon(null, g, x, y);
}
```

but it tells me

"The method paintComponent(Graphics) is undefined for the type Object"

What am i doing wrong?? Please help me

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Why are you doing custom painting? Just use a JLabel to display the Icon.

Comment: How would i do that??

Comment: You would use the setIcon(...) method of a JLabel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more information and examples. I would suggest you keep a link to the tutorial handy since it has section all the Swing basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because you are not extending the correct class.  You need to extend `JPanel` or any other class that contains it in order to call this super class.  Right now it is looking for the `paintComponent()` method in the default super class which is `Object` and there is no `paintComponent()` method there.

```
public class myClass extends JPanel {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :D As soon as i can i'll mark this as correct

Comment: +1 since it answers the question. However, @user2687097, why are you doing custom painting? Just use a JLabel with an Icon. What are the values of x/y? Did you override the getPreferredSize() of this class to return the size of the image plus the x/y offsets?

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `super.paintComponent(g)` is looking for a `paintComponent()` method from the super class. It's probably because you're trying to use this method in a class that is not a subclass of `JComponent`, which is the class with the `paintComponent()` method. See [JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html).

More than likely, you want to make your class a subclass of `JPanel`, or any other class that is a subclass of `JComponent`

Comment: Yeah i had to extend JPanel as jl2975 said